# Is file upload control is available in html helper class in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is file upload control is available in html helper class in asp.net mvc if not then how should we use file upload control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=bc137b6b-d8d0-47d1-9795-f8814f7d1903).

You need to make an `<input type="file" />` element in your form, then check  `Request.Files` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use SlickUpload.  I'm not the owner or some shill paid by the owner.  It's just a great product.

http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/

Comment: Yes.  Click that link.  It mentions MVC support.